# Is there is any way to get the selected columns after saving the filter view in Jira?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, atlassian-connect, jira-filter

I am new to Jira and I created jira custom app using Atlassian connect express.  
 
I used api from https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/
Atlassian components from https://atlassian.design/components/
In my app there is two filter dropdown is present, one is for columns and another is status of issues in jira. 
 
For saving the filter view, I followed the below steps:-

- Create filter on save button. (/rest/api/3/filter.)
- Search filter for get all created filter. (/rest/api/3/filter/search).

But the problem occur after create filter that only the status filter is saved properly, but columns are not saved in it.

I tried to set columns after the filter is created but it not work for me.

- Used set columns api. (PUT /rest/api/3/filter/{id}/columns)
- Also try to get columns. (GET /rest/api/3/filter/{id}/columns).

Here I attached my github link please refer it.

- https://github.com/kuldip-estatic/jira-plugin-project
  For starting the app you can read readme.md file after clone the project. 
   
  When I save the view, I also pass the selected columns but, I cannot retrieve from the GET API.

Please help me in this if any one has idea about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do that:

you make a GET to https:///rest/api/latest/filter/<filterId>/columns

and the jira should response with something like:

```
[
    {
        "label": "Issue Type",
        "value": "issuetype"
    },
    {
        "label": "Priority",
        "value": "priority"
    },
    {
        "label": "Created",
        "value": "created"
    },
    {
        "label": "Status",
        "value": "status"
    },
    {
        "label": "Key",
        "value": "issuekey"
    },
    {
        "label": "Summary",
        "value": "summary"
    },
    {
        "label": "Creator",
        "value": "creator"
    },
    {
        "label": "Assignee",
        "value": "assignee"
    },
    {
        "label": "Story Points",
        "value": "customfield_124"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding,
I created new filter and save it.
By using this api rest/api/3/filter/search I got list of created filters with id.
I tried /rest/api/latest/filter/10082/columns , but it shows the error of page can’t be found.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the GET error could be that your filter doesn't have its own column config yet.
If you create manually a filter and choose in columns the option "Filter" then the GET works properly.
I'm still figuring out how to set that config with Jira API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).